# Ruby on Rails, Highcharts how to render data dynamically for fields instead of columns

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

On the application I am working on I am rendering data from columns in my table - for example:

(Model) **note.rb**

```
       def self.getStudentname
            data = []
            self.studentnames.each do |type3|
              data << self.type3_count(type3)
            end
            data 
        end

....
private


  def self.studentnames
    pluck(:studentname).uniq
  end

  def self.type3_count(type3)
    where(studentname: type3).count
  end
```

(Controller) **notes_controller.rb**

```
def dashboard_student
      @sData = Note.getStudentname()
      @students = Note.studentnames
end
```

(View) **dashboard_student.html.erb**

```
....
 xAxis: {
            categories: <%=raw @students.to_json %>,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
 .....
 series: [{
           name: 'Number of Notes By Student',
           data: <%= @sData %>
      }]
```

As you can see I am getting data from the "studentnames" column in the notes table and rendering on the bar chart in the view which works great.

I am looking to get information for fields in columns so, for example, if I have a column named "greivance" and within that a field labeled "late" how would I get information for all the students that are late keeping the rendering dynamic as above?

Any guidance much appreciated. Thanks. Can provide more code if needed.